# Salesforce history log

Tags: soql, history-tracking, sales-cloud

Does anyone know if Salesforce keeps a history log of record changes and is able to provide that for a fee?

In addition, SF by default keeps history up to 18 months - is there a way to get all the old data?

And lastly, there probably isn't a way for Admin/Dev to get field history changes for a field that wasn't tracked in the first place, or is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know if Salesforce keeps a history log of record changes and is able to provide that for a fee?

They can provide a log of records that were changed via [Historical Event Logs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212606&language=en_US&type=1), but that only tells you record-level details (e.g. user viewed X record, user edited Y record). It's essentially a log of every URL the user accessed on the server, but doesn't include the POST information, so field details are not accessible.

> In addition, SF by default keeps history up to 18 months - is there a way to get all the old data?

You can request a change to the behavior, but it is not retroactive, so any changes not already logged can't be retrieved.

> And lastly, there probably isn't a way for Admin/Dev to get field history changes for a field that wasn't tracked in the first place, or is there?

Related to the above answer, no.